# How can I do a partial match on a "text" field?

Tags: elasticsearch

Firstly I'm new to ElasticSearch.

I'm porting an old SQL script with a bunch of `LIKE '%' + @searchTerm + '%'` clauses to elastic search.

I've indexed my documents and I've got a property like

```
"noteNo": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }
    }
},
```

This field contains sequantial numbers, but stored as a string.

e.g

```
34567
34568
34569
...
45691
45692
45693
```

I want to be able to search for "456" and get all those documents that match that partial string, just like the SQL `LIKE '%456%'` would give.

I've seen wildcard queries but read that has performance issues, so my super basic query right now is

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "350",
            "fields": [
                ... other fields elided 
                "noteNo"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives me nothing back.

I'm running ES 7.9.1 on Windows and indexing with the .net NEST client. I've done nothing to change the analysis of any fields.

How can I search for these substrings in a way analaous to a SQL `LIKE '%' + @searchTerm + '%'` ?

Comment: ngram tokenizer - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html. 

An example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706304/bring-back-all-relevant-results-when-using-ngrams-with-elasticsearch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can use [N-gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) that first breaks text down into
> words whenever it encounters one of a list of specified characters,
> then it emits N-grams of each word of the specified length.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and results.

**Index Mapping**

```
 {
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "my_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 5,
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "max_ngram_diff": 50
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Analyze API**

```
POST/_analyze

{
  "analyzer" : "my_analyzer",
  "text" : "34567"
}
```

The following tokens are generated

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "34",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 2,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "345",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 3,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "3456",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "34567",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 5,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "token": "45",
            "start_offset": 1,
            "end_offset": 3,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "token": "456",
            "start_offset": 1,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 5
        },
        {
            "token": "4567",
            "start_offset": 1,
            "end_offset": 5,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 6
        },
        {
            "token": "56",
            "start_offset": 2,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 7
        },
        {
            "token": "567",
            "start_offset": 2,
            "end_offset": 5,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 8
        },
        {
            "token": "67",
            "start_offset": 3,
            "end_offset": 5,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 9
        }
    ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "title": "456"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "stof_63976447",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.074107975,
                "_source": {
                    "title": 34567
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "stof_63976447",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.074107975,
                "_source": {
                    "title": 34568
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "stof_63976447",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.074107975,
                "_source": {
                    "title": 34569
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "stof_63976447",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 0.074107975,
                "_source": {
                    "title": 45691
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "stof_63976447",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "5",
                "_score": 0.074107975,
                "_source": {
                    "title": 45692
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "stof_63976447",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "6",
                "_score": 0.074107975,
                "_source": {
                    "title": 45693
                }
            }
        ]
```